# How to save specific data in mysql database

Tags: mysql, save

How can I save f/cm3 value in tbl_unit table?

[image]

3 is exponent;

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Store the code of symbol for example

For example superscript 3

https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/punctuation/superscript-three/